# Get ModuleNeme from ProcessThread.StartAddress

Tags: pinvoke, dbghelp

> ProcessThread.StartAddress is the memory address of the function that
>   the operating system called that started this thread.

How I get the function name and Module name?

for get function name I found [SymFromAddr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx) but for Module name I need help.

Comment: You can just hard-code it.  The module name is ntdll.dll, the function name is RtlUserThreadStart().  ProcessThread.StartAddress is only useful in old Windows versions, XP was the last one.